# search a topic in my posts

Tags: support, search

When I search in my post to look a topic, I don't know if there is a way to shortcut the review of each post. is there a mean to adapt the "Search Q&A" window to my own posts or to the post of someone else specifically?

Comment: Beyond what DoubleAA said, if you are really lazy like me, you can also click on yourself in the top bar, then add topics in the search bar on the right

Comment: Can you explain a little more, I am very lazy but not very expert

Comment: In the bar at the top (on the Web at least), if you click on your picture, the search bar on the right automatically becomes a search in your posts, i.e., it has your userID number filled in. Try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the search bar include `user:9215` to get all of your posts, or anyone else's user number to get their posts. You can also user `user:me` if you don't remember your own user number.

See this help page for more search tips: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: How can I find the number of user of anyone?

Comment: If you click anyone's user name to go their user page, the URL will look like ...stackexchange.com/users/#### and that's the number that represents them

Comment: @DoubleAAi noticed that in the computer it appears also in te "Search on Mi Yodeya window user 1234